# Summarize columns in dataframe for a large dataset

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset (around 200K rows) that looks something like -

```
timestamp,cell_id,crnti,enodeb_id,cqi,
1603208435646,3,39062,21519,1,
1603208435946,3,39063,21519,1,
1603208435146,3,39064,21519,2,
1603208435346,3,39064,21519,1,
1603208435546,3,39065,21519,3,
1603208435746,3,39065,21519,1,
1603208435846,3,39062,21519,1,
1603208435946,3,39065,21519,1,
```

I want to summarize all the records (per crnti) in this format -

```
cell_id,crnti,enodeb_id,cqi,distance_km,session_duration
```

Here Session duration is calculated for each crnti using the timestamps. So as an example for crnti = 39065 there are 3 records so session_duration (delta of 1st and last record) = 1603208435946 - 1603208435546 = 400 msec
and so on.
cqi is avg all cqi values = AVG(3,1,1) = 1.66

For crnti which only have one record the session duration is default = 4 sec

```
cell_id,crnti,enodeb_id,cqi,session_duration(msec)
3,39065,21519,1.66,400
3,39062,21519,1,4000
```

How can I do this in pandas in a way that is efficient. I have been thinking about doing using loops but that seems very inefficient. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with named aggregations, then subtract maximal and minimal values with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for drop columns and set `4000` if count is `1` by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['cell_id','crnti','enodeb_id']).agg(cqi = ('cqi','mean'),
                                                     first = ('timestamp', 'min'),
                                                     last = ('timestamp','max'),
                                                     count = ('cqi', 'size'))
df['session_duration(msec)'] = df.pop('last').sub(df.pop('first'))
df.loc[df.pop('count').eq(1), 'session_duration(msec)'] = 4000
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   cell_id  crnti  enodeb_id       cqi  session_duration(msec)
0        3  39062      21519  1.000000                     200
1        3  39063      21519  1.000000                    4000
2        3  39064      21519  1.500000                     200
3        3  39065      21519  1.666667                     400
```